# Parsing custom xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I have an xml file of following format :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<execute time="0.59">
<exec name="recursive_a" loops="3" fail="2" skipped="0">
<testcase tname="test_a" name="test.cpp" time="0.50">
<pass>
001,test,pass
</pass>
</testcase>
</exec>
</execute>
```

how can i parse "recursive_a" string from this xml using python? (i am using minidom xml parser)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for basic documentation and tutorials. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry , I have very limited knowledge in xml parsing libs. I 've used getElementsByTagName("pass) to get data in the tag and process it. I read the documentation for minidom and its confusing. I want to parse fields in exec and testcase tags .

Comment: It looks like you want a field (`name`) from the `exec` element, so you would need to start with `getElementsByTagName("exec")`. At that point, the [`getAttribute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.getAttribute) method will probably get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

With `xml.etree.ElementTree` and `pandas` one solution could be:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse('Code3r.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:
    if elem.tag == "exec":
        # print(elem.attrib) or with pandas
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(elem.attrib, orient='index')
        print(df.T.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
       name loops fail skipped
recursive_a     3    2       0
```